# Is “since five years old” grammatical?

Tags: prepositions

> I’ve lived here **since** I was five years old.

I know that **since** is used as a conjunction here.
Can I use **since** as a preposition and leave out “I was”?

> I’ve lived here since five years old.

Comment: No, but you could say "...since the age of five".

Comment: You could also say since _since my fifth birthday_

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use "since five years old" because *since*, when it means "from a definite past time to now", needs to be followed by a noun phrase or a time reference.  *Five years old* is an adjectival phrase.

Reference: [Since - English Grammar Today - Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/since)